# tikz - maintain scale while adding plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to superpose some plots like this one, but shifted in the x-axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}

    \pgfplotsset{
        standard/.style={%Axis format configuration
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            enlarge x limits=0.15,
            enlarge y limits=0.15,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east},
            every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=white}}
            }
        }

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                standard,
                domain = -10:10,
                xlabel={$t$},
                ylabel={$y(t)$}]
                \addplot[samples=101,black,thick] {exp(-(x/4)^2)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In particular, I would like to add 20 extra units both to the left and the right of the origin of the x-axis, in order to obtain

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}

    \pgfplotsset{
        standard/.style={%Axis format configuration
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            enlarge x limits=0.15,
            enlarge y limits=0.15,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east},
            every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=white}}
            }
        }

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                standard,
                domain = -30:30,
                xlabel={$t$},
                ylabel={$y(t)$}]
                \addplot[samples=101,black,thick] {exp(-(x/4)^2)};
                \addplot[samples=101,black,thick] {exp(-((x - 10)/4)^2)};
                \addplot[samples=101,black,thick] {exp(-((x + 10)/4)^2)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

so that the function `exp(-(x/4)^2)` is superposed to its 10-units forward and backward shifted versions, `exp(-((x - 10)/4)^2)` and `exp(-((x - 10)/4)^2)`.

I tried to specify `[xmin,xmax]` as options in each `\addplot`, but it gives error.

If I don't specify anything, the plot is correct, but the length of a 60-units wide x-axis (second example) is the same as the length of the former 20-units wide x-axis (first example), so the plots are horizontally "zoomed-out".

Is there any other way to avoid this tediout zoom-out and preserve the scale of the first code?

Comment: Use  `height` and `width` keys together for both of them. And increase the width of the second one.

Comment: Or use `xscale=value` and adjust suitably. For example `xscale=1.5` for three graphs and `xscale=0.75` for single graph.

Comment: Did one of the tricks solve your problem or do you need further assistance?